# How to use MS Graph in a Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to run an action filter any time one of my controllers is called from my front end to check if a token issued by Azure AD is still active. If I run this code in one of my controllers methods directly the code is fine and does as follows:

1. If token is expired or cache has been cleared, MS Graph SDK returns a redirect to MS Login
2. If token is valid it runs the MS Graph API and returns the results as normal.

In this ActionFilter below if the scenario is 1 the code just stops and errors out. In visual studio it actually generates the following service error

```
    {Code: generalException
    Message: An error occurred sending the request.
    }

{Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent. 
 ---> MSAL.NetCore.4.46.0.0.MsalUiRequiredException: 
    ErrorCode: user_null
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. 
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ClientApplicationBaseExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenSilentParameters silentParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForWebAppWithAccountFromCacheAsync(IConfidentialClientApplication application, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String tenantId, MergedOptions mergedOptions, String userFlow, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable`1 scopes, String authenticationScheme, String tenantId, String userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
    StatusCode: 0 
    ResponseBody:  
    Headers: 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable`1 scopes, String authenticationScheme, String tenantId, String userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)}
```

So basically the ActionFilter does not automatically redirect the user to the MS Login screen or generate any response to send back to the front end for that matter. It just errors out even with a try and catch statement. So is there any way to do this? My action filter is set as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

public class CheckTokenFilter : IActionFilter
{

private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
private readonly string[] initialScopes;
private readonly MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler _consentHandler;

public CheckTokenFilter(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IConfiguration configuration, MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler consentHandler)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    initialScopes = configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
    this._consentHandler = consentHandler;
}

public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    //noop
}

public async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    User currentUser = null;

    try
    {
        currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    }
    // Catch CAE exception from Graph SDK
    catch (ServiceException svcex) when (svcex.Message.Contains("Continuous access evaluation resulted in claims challenge"))
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{svcex}");
            string claimChallenge = WwwAuthenticateParameters.GetClaimChallengeFromResponseHeaders(svcex.ResponseHeaders);
            _consentHandler.ChallengeUser(initialScopes, claimChallenge);
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            _consentHandler.HandleException(ex2);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Current method that is working based on answer below:

```
    public class CheckTokenFilter : IActionFilter
{

    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    private string SignedInRedirectUri;

    public CheckTokenFilter(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        SignedInRedirectUri = configuration["AzureAd:SignedInRedirectUri"];
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //noop
    }

    public async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //First we check if token is valid and if not it will generate an error and challenge user causing a redirect which is caught in our program.cs. It sends a 403 error to the front end to load the login page.
        User currentUser = null;

        try
        {
            currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        }
        // Catch CAE exception from Graph SDK
        catch
        {
            context.Result = new ChallengeResult(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                RedirectUri = SignedInRedirectUri
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using something like:

context.Result = new ChallengeResult(*Your Scheme*)

I use something similar in my solution, but I use:

```
    [Authorize]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(*******AuthenticationFilter))]
```

This way if the token is not valid, it will go off and challenge the user before it goes to the filter.  The filter can then do additional work once the user is authenticated at a high level.  The filter just throws an exception in my case, as it shouldn't get into a bad state.

Comment: Can you expand on this more? I am confused as to how you are saying to implement what you wrote above into my code. Ie are you saying to remove that simple token check for the user info and replace with the challenge user?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Two things, the context.result line is the way I believe to validly redirect from a filter, vs trying to invoke something else that you have and it doesn't work.  The next part is just trying to suggest another approach which you may have discounted already, it is out of the box stuff, which just works.   It is doing everything you are doing but hiding it from you.  May not be relevant to your situation, but the former should help you get what you are trying to do working.  A quick search on context.result and/or challengeresult should hopefully get you moving along.

Comment: No worries and I implemented your code. It does allow me to complete the challenge. The issue is challenge seems to always cause a redirect. Is this intentional even if the user is already logged in and the token is valid? Since I have a SPA as my view in my MVC app, I actually capture any redirects from Azure AD (which the challenge is doing) and return a 403 error instead so my front end can send my app to a login page with a button to manually do the challenge if the token is expired. So using this challenge just keeps sending me to that page. Can I challenge user without a redirect?

Comment: That is one reason I was trying to do the MS GRAPH API call because I wanted to check if it worked and if I did then it should continue on to access the controller (no redirect) where as if it did not then it should cause the redirect.

Comment: Not sure I 100% follow, if you have the challenge code in the catch then it can't be running it every time unless your user token is either broken or doesn't have a token?  If you call challenge it will always challenge regardless of token or not.  To your point on you want to intercept the challenge, don't do it this way.  You just need logic which is to allow it to end and return to the controller if the token is present, if it is caught without the token, then use my suggestion, but just redirect to the page you want it to hit in the first place with the login button?

Comment: Thanks for the info. So yea what method would you use to check if the token is there and works without challenging? I added some code to my original question which is based on yours and it is working like a charm but maybe testing the graph api is more expensive? Maybe something less expensive is better? Also, in regards to catching the challenge. How else would your SPA frontend be able to handle a redirect if its using axios or fetch? Any redirects from a challenge should result in CORS errors. Unless you are using Blazor or some MS frontend right?

Comment: For instance maybe i should use await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(initialScopes) instead of await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync() . Not sure which makes more sense since either should draw an MSAL error if there is a token issue i think.

Comment: Asking for a token and handling it not having one, seems sensible.  The pattern I have seen is a token refresh method, see what they are doing or the logic of them getting called.  I know some MS patterns have the concept of in-memory cache so you aren't calling externally at all, unless you actually need a new one.  Not used it, but depends on how many users you are supporting.  I don't know about the SPA question, we do have one, but it is Blazor/MAUI and it is using the out of the box stuff as mentioned too, rather than graph calls.  The Azure AD github page has huge amounts of samples.